# How to make a sub class return an object (copy) of itself in a virtual method

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, vector, covariant-return-types

I am currently trying to understand inheritance in C++, but I am quite confused as to why I can't make a descendant class of my main class return an object of the same type as said descendant class from some operator methods I overloaded.

The classes are defined like this (this is an abridged version):

```
template <class elem>
class Vect
{
    public:
        Vect() = default;
        virtual Vect operator+(const elem&);
        virtual Vect operator-(const elem&);
}

template <class elem, std::size_t taille=10>
class Vect_fixe: public Vect<elem>
{
public:
    Vect_fixe() = default;
    virtual Vect_fixe operator+(const elem&);
    virtual Vect_fixe operator-(const elem&);
private:
    elem vecteur[taille] = {0};
}
```

And this is how the methods are defined:

```
template <class elem, std::size_t taille>
Vect_fixe<elem,taille> Vect_fixe<elem, taille>::operator+(const elem& operand)
{
    Vect_fixe<elem, taille> temp_v;
    for (int i=0; i<taille; i++)
        {
        temp_v[i] = vecteur[i];
        temp_v[i] += operand;
        }
    return temp_v;
}

template <class elem, std::size_t taille>
Vect_fixe<elem,taille> Vect_fixe<elem, taille>::operator-(const elem& operand)
{
    Vect_fixe<elem, taille> temp_v;
    for (int i=0; i<taille; i++)
        {
        temp_v[i] = vecteur[i];
        temp_v[i] -= operand;
        }
    return temp_v;
```

So in this case, both methods should return a copy of the vector + operand, but it doesn't work when I use inheritance. If I remove the first class' virtual methods (Vect) from the file, everything works fine. Otherwise the compiler complains about an invalid covariant return type.

```
main.cpp:88:24:   required from here
main.cpp:50:24: error: invalid covariant return type for 'Vect_fixe<elem, taille> Vect_fixe<elem, taille>::operator+(const elem&) [with elem = int; long unsigned int taille = 35ul]'
 Vect_fixe<elem,taille> Vect_fixe<elem, taille>::operator+(const elem& operand)
                        ^
In file included from main.cpp:9:0:
Vect.hpp:25:22: error:   overriding 'Vect<elem> Vect<elem>::operator+(const elem&) [with elem = int]'
         virtual Vect operator+(const elem&);
                      ^
main.cpp:62:24: error: invalid covariant return type for 'Vect_fixe<elem, taille> Vect_fixe<elem, taille>::operator-(const elem&) [with elem = int; long unsigned int taille = 35ul]'
 Vect_fixe<elem,taille> Vect_fixe<elem, taille>::operator-(const elem& operand)
                        ^
In file included from main.cpp:9:0:
Vect.hpp:26:22: error:   overriding 'Vect<elem> Vect<elem>::operator-(const elem&) [with elem = int]'
         virtual Vect operator-(const elem&);
```

I tried doing it with a reference, but returning a reference to a temporary object is undefined behaviour as far as I know, and I wish for the methods to return a copy of my object and not directly modify it.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Inheritance and copying don't mix well and I advise you against trying that while "trying to understand inheritance in C++". If you want to try it nevertheless, you should know that you **must** return a reference or a pointer. In practise this means you have to return a pointer and you have to allocate the result on the free store, and you have to manage its lifetime from now on. Not a very novice-friendly proposition but that's what we have in C++. By the way why do you think inheritance is not a key design element of STL?

Comment: @n.m. I see. The way to do that would be to create an object using new and then delete it when I don't need it anymore? I remember having read that smart pointers were pretty useful in cases like that, but I have no idea how to use them. As for your question, I have no idea but I don't think I even understand the question :o I am very new to templates as well, so I wouldn't know.

Comment: You could try returning `std::shared_ptr<Vect>`

Comment: Returning `std::shared_ptr<Vect>` is an option, but then the return type be covariant. Convariant return types only work for plain pointers and references. There is a workaround for this, but do you really need to learn about workarounds before learning the basics of inheritance? And the answer to the question is *because inheritance doesn't work well in this situation* (and you now see one of the reasons why).

Comment: @n.m. Oh i see. Well unfortunately this is an assignment and that's the way I am supposed to do it. Well I guess I'll just play around with it and see how it goes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I could point out is that you are not doing inheritance as you wanted to use. I can guess that you intention was to use `Vect` as an interface and override it with `Vect_fixe`.

But, because the return types are different, they become covariant return types. This mechanism requires return by pointer or reference (so the covariant types can be cast from/to each other).

If you intend to use `Vect` as a general reference handler for all its subtypes, then you should really be returning references/pointers.

> I tried doing it with a reference, but returning a reference to a temporary object is undefined behaviour as far as I know, and I wish for the methods to return a copy of my object and not directly modify it.

If you return a reference you can extend its lifetime by using `static` local.

```
int& returnByReference()
{
     static int x = 5; // static ensures x doesn't go out of scope when we return it by reference
     return x;
}

int value = returnByReference(); // case A -- ok, treated as return by value
const int &cref = returnByValue(); // case C -- ok, the lifetime of return value is extended to the lifetime of cref
```

Not good idea to follow for life, though. As @n.m. said in the commends, inheritance and copy don't mix well because overloading will eventually introduce ambiguities or unavoidable but undesired casts.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work for now. It's unfortunate I can't make it work in any other way.

Comment: It does work, but please don't make this you standard style. Always have in mind that inheritance naturally leads to using pointers to deal with subtypes. That's the philosophy: being capable of using base class pointers to handle derived classes (that's why you declare methods `virtual` in the first place).

Comment: Making it static local is an **extremely** bad idea.